# Shorthand of Get[]

Tags: import, syntax

I thought that `<< expr` was just a shorthand form of `Get[expr]`. I have now found that it clearly isn't. Namely it holds `expr` and converts it to a string. Thus `<< fileName[file]`, will not work if `fileName[file]` is some function that has been Set (delayed or not) to the file location. Get[fileName[file]] will work.

The documentation is not that clear on this difference. My confusion has mostly been cleared up, but I thought I should still post since there does not seem to be any post on this and others might have the same confusion. Also evaluate does not seem to help things. I had hoped it would force an evaluation before `expr` is converted to a string, but alas, it just gets held and converted to a string too. So should I just be using the full form Get in these situations or am I still missing something about the usage of `<<`.

---

Or instead I can use the shorthand like this

ReleaseHold@Map[ToExpression, Hold[<< expr], {2}]

but then it is not exactly shorter anymore.

Comment: It seems to address all your doubts but let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: @Kuba, it does. Thanks! (I should have thought of searching for issues with similar functions (>>, >>>). Well next person with this problem should have an easier job finding that question now that it's also linked from the Get perspective.)